# Add columns to each other (not combine!)

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, multiple-columns

I want to add columns that are right now next to each other beneath each other so that I have only one single, really long column in the end.

Since I have 150 columns to combine into that one long column, an efficient solution would be great.

Short example:

What it looks like now:

```
A B C
A B C
A B C
```

How I want it to look like:

```
A  
A
A
B
B
B
C
C
C
```

Comment: You need to explain a little better what you're trying to achieve... Do you want to alter your database? Just get a report?

Comment: If you are starting out with a matrix, you could use `myVec <- c(myMat)`.

Answer (score 2):

`unlist` does what you want.

```
Data = read.table(text="A B C
A B C
A B C")
Data
  V1 V2 V3
1  A  B  C
2  A  B  C
3  A  B  C
unlist(Data)
V11 V12 V13 V21 V22 V23 V31 V32 V33 
  A   A   A   B   B   B   C   C   C
```

Comment: unlist by itself will not produce a column.

Comment: `data.frame(unlist(Data))`  if you like :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're starting with a data frame:

```
dd <- data.frame(V1=rep("A",3),V2=rep("B",3),V3=rep("C",3))
```

Turn it into a matrix and then strip the dimensions:

```
c(as.matrix(dd))
```

You can turn it back into a 1-column matrix with `matrix()` or `cbind()` or back int a 1-column data frame with `data.frame()`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `gather/select`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
gather(dd) %>%
         select(value)
```